# If I have a LINEST polynomial function, how can I stretch it horizontally based on existing data points?

Tags: regression, excel

I'm trying to create a cash flow curve from past accounting data, and utilizing its 'shape' to predict future cash flow curves. I work in construction, and I want a representative curve 'shape' for each of the 50 accounting codes (which represents different types of work by subcontractors).
To predict future cash flows, I'd use the existing cash flow shape, apply the current projected total accounting code (subcontractor contract) value , as well as the current projected total account code duration. The goal is to create a new cash flow curve with just these two variables.

By using `LINEST(y, x^{1,2,3})` I'm able to generate coefficients for the resulting third-order polynomial. This is fine as a representation of my existing account code data, but I want to use it for any account code value and duration. And to do that I need to recalculate all the coefficients.

[image: LINEST estimated values]

LINEST coefficients:
[image: LINEST coefficients]

My understanding is that it is easy to stretch this curve vertically to fit the new project's account code value by simply factoring it up, but to stretch it horizontally to fit the new project's account code duration, I need to solve it for two unknowns.
In other words, vertical stretching is basically af(x), but horizontal stretching will have to be like f(mx + n) or something. There'll have to be both a stretch and a translation, since I'll have to stretch it horizontally, but to keep the start date at day 0, I'll have to shift the graph horizontally as well.

I can't exactly solve for m or n in this case, even though I know f(0) = 0 and f(end date) = total account code value, because the polynomial is a regression equation with R2 of 0.98 and not a perfect fit.

Ideally I want to do this formulaically or with vba so it can be applied to any account code value and duration.

I noticed a video on Youtube calculating polynomial regressions with actual math (and not LINEST), which involved PDE's and Gaussian Elimination, words that I heard of ten years ago but is way over my head now. I feel there must be an easier way so I'd appreciate any help.